# Find maximum volume of sphere inscribed inside a cone of circular base

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry, optimization, volume

A sphere is inscribed in a right circular cone with volume of $10$ $cm^3$. Find the maximum volume of the sphere.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-find-the-volume-of-a-sphere-inscribed-in-the-right-circular-cone-with-a-radius-of-1-6-inches-and-a-height-of-5-7-inches

Comment: I think you can find the radius of the base circle from the volume. Then take a slice of the cone through the center of the base and inscribe a circle in the triangle to find the radius of the sphere

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2014_AMC_10B_Problems/Problem_23

Comment: sorry, but how to relate radius of cone and radius of sphere?

Comment: @nirmala first you find the radius of the cone. Then you take the triangle with the base being the diameter of the cone base, and the sides on the cone. You inscribe a circle into that triangle, it’s radius will be equal to the radius of the sphere you want to find

Answer (score 0):

[image]

From the cross-section diagram, the volumes of the cone and the sphere are respectively,
$$V_c=\frac13 \pi R^3\tan2\theta,\>\>\>\>\>V_s = \frac{4}3\pi R^3\tan^3\theta$$

Eliminate $R$,

$$V_s = \frac{4\tan^3\theta}{\tan2\theta}V_c=2\tan^2\theta(1-\tan^2\theta)V_c$$

Set $V_s'(\theta) = 0$ to find the maximum value at $\tan\theta = \frac1{\sqrt2}$. Then, plug it into above expression to obtain the maximum volume of the sphere,

$$V_s^{max} = \frac12 V_c$$

which happens to be half volume of the cone.

Comment: thank you so much. May i know what tool do you used to generate the geometry shape diagram?

Comment: @nirmala - you’re welcome. I used MS Paint